# Flutter- SearchableDropdown

Tags: flutter

There is 2 SearchableDropdown, One is **Company** and the Second is **Account**
,Based on a selection of **Company**, **Account** SearchableDropdown should fill the data.

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What widget you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use searchable dropdown package hope your problem is solved

1. [searchable_dropdown](https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown)
2. [dropdown_search](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search)